# IE is not loading Custom Fonts (Google Fonts and Icon font from Divi Theme)

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-11, http-status-codes, webfonts, http-status-code-304

So I have a very strange issue going on here, First time the page loads it doesn't load any Google Fonts or the Icon font pack from the wordpress theme Divi. The content returns a 304 status code. Then if you click the logo (or any nav item) then all the fonts load correctly and return a status code of 200. But then if you hold shift and refresh any page they go back to 304 status and are not loading.

Made a quick screen share video to show the above.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15jAjqRP5PqjPYn69ueLfkTVC3k_ZVtJF/view

I have tried a few suggestion that I found on here on SO but nothing has helped. I tried to disable all Cache Plugins in Wordpress and a few .HTACCESS file mods

```
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
```

Any other suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Never use "Expires 0". Instead, use `Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"`. Not sure if this is the root of the problem, though.

Comment: @Damocles - Curious to why not on expires 0? I actually took that from this article that was up voted over 2600 times.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407

Comment: Can you please try to add these meta tags to your web page? <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1"> Check whether it makes any difference or not. Let us know about your test results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I really appreciate the suggestion but didnt have any effect here

Comment: ttf fonts may create issues in the IE browser If possible then try to make a test with wotf or otf font file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to check the website SSL certificate and if fonts and website URL both are HTTPS:

Also try to follow the following article attached below:

If you uploaded a custom font in a Divi module but it's not loading, then it's likely to be an issue with the font format.

Always make sure to upload both ttf and otf versions of the font file for maximum browser compatibility. To do it, first go to https://convertio.co/ and convert the ttf font file you may have to otf version (or vice versa).

Once converted, upload both the files for a font in a module, like this:

You need to press CTRL Key (Command Key for Mac) to select both versions of the font while uploading. OR, you can click on CHOOSE FONT FILES button two times to upload both versions of the font.

Do make sure that ALL is selected in supported font weights.

After these steps, you can apply this font to various elements on your website and it will work fine.

For fixing broken links: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-wordpress-links